C++：Initializing std::queue variable in a class error:The member "test :: tasks" is not a valid class member template
Details
I am trying to initialize a std::queue<Task<T>>("Task" is a struct),but VSCode alerts me that The member "test::tasks" is not a valid class member template. And I wonder what went wrong and how to solve it
Code to reproduce
No need to run this
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class test{
    public:
        test()=default;
    private:
        template<typename T>
        struct task{
            std::function<std::vector<T>(std::vector<T>)> func;
        };
        template<typename T>
        std::queue<task<T>> tasks;
};

Thanks for help!

TL;DR: template<typename T> class Test { ... };

Thanks,the problem has been solved successfully!

You cannot have a member variable that is a template, because in C++ sizeof(test) will have to be a constant. And all tests have to be of the same size.
Can you perhaps move the template to be for the whole class, and not for the individual members?

The problem has been solved successfully with your help!Thanks!
